# How do you assign value to a multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

As a beginner for c++, I'm using the C++ primer as my textbook. I just got to the multidimensional array part. This is the code in the book about assigning values to such an array, but I don't quite understand..

```
constexpr size_t rowCnt = 3, colCnt = 4;

int ia[rowCnt][colCnt]; 

for (size_t i = 0; i != rowCnt; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j != colCnt; ++j) {
        ia[i][j] = i * colCnt + j;
    }
}
```

How does `ia[i][j] = i * colCnt + j;` assign value to the array?

Comment: Note that `ia[i][j]` does not assign value "to the array". It assigns value only to a single array element. The assigned value is calculated as `i * colCnt + j`, but it can be calculated any other way as well.

Answer (score 3):

To access element number "x" in an array you call array[x] right? And to assign a value to that index you call array[x] = "something".

In a multidimensional array, the element at "x" is another array, so:

ai[i][j] becomes (ai array at index i)[j] .

I hope that makes sense.

What is then assigned on the right side of the equal sign is irrelevant, in your case because of the loops you'll get something like

0, 1, 2

3, 4, 5

6, 7, 8

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for the explanation, but "ia[i][j] = i * colCnt + j" this is what still confuses me. How does this assign value to a multidimensional array?  Like what does "i*colCnt" do, and what is the purpose of putting a "+j" here?

Comment: i, colCnt and j are all integers defined earlier, so i*colCnt + j is just another integer that is assigned to the array. Try printing the values in the array and you'll see what is happening! You could also put for example "ia[i][j] = 3" to fill the entire multidimensional array with the number 3.

Comment: great idea! but this is the error it returns : Array index 3 is past the end of the array (which contains 3 elements) sry, but what's going on here?

Comment: that means that somehow you called ai[3][j], which doesn't exist. The elements that are defined are ai[0][0], ai[1][0], ai[2][0], ai[0][1], ai[1][1] ... up to ai[2][3].

Answer (score 1):

So you have an array of three rows, each row consists of array of four columns.

To address the first column in the first row as "ia[0][0]" to address the second column in the first row use "ia[0][1]".
To address the last column in the last row use "ia[2][3]".

The compiler needs to calculate the address of the row you require using the "i" variable: "ia[i]" then calculate the position of the column within that row using the "j" variable: "ia[i][j]".

Answer (score 0):

From your code

```
int ia[rowCnt][colCnt];
```

This is much the same like thi
int is[3][4];
This mean that your array can hold 3 items (values) in row and 4 in the column.

Then you used a for loops to loop through every index of the array, which you use nasted loop, so the first loop is for the row, and the second for the column.

In the first loop

```
for(size_t i = 0; i != rowCnt; i++)
```

So this first loop is for looping through and incrementing the value of i untill it is rowCnt; (3)

Same goes for the second loop.

```
for(size_t j = 0; j != colCnt; j++)
```

***Also remember that, the innner loop will always be executed completely while the utter loop is executed once.***

So this mean when i = 0 and j = 0; ai[i][j] = i * colCnt + j;
which means.
In the first row and the the first column, give it the value of
i * colCnt + j;

So it keeps on like that until all the values are field out
.

I'm not sure if you understand, but I hope I've answered your question.